# Proving the product topology and standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ are the same

Tags: general-topology

I was trying to prove that the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the same as the topology induced by the euclidean metric. My attempt was to find a square that fits inside an open ball in the first case, and an open ball that fits inside a rectangle in the second case to do this. Let me know if my attempt is on the right track.

Attempt:Yes the product topology on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is the same as the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $p=(x_1,y_2) \in U$. Then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_{\epsilon}(p)=\{(x_2,y_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2|\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}<\epsilon\} \subset U$. Then $(x_1-\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}},x_1+\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}) \times (y_1-\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}},y_1+\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}) \subset B_{\epsilon}(p)=\{(x_2,y_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2|\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}<\epsilon\} \subset U$

So $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

Conversely suppose that $W$ is open in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. Then for each point $(x,y) \in U$ there is a basis element $(a,b) \times (c,d)$ centered about $(x,y)$ such that $(a,b) \times (c,d) \subset W$. Then $(x,y)=(\frac{a+b}{2},\frac{c+d}{2})$. Choose $\epsilon=\text{min}\{\frac{|b-a|}{2},\frac{|c-d|}{2}\}$. Then $B_{\epsilon}((x,y))\subset (a,b) \times (c,d) \subset W$. So $W$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is indeed a valid way to show that these topologies are the same. Missing details: You should show by computation that indeed

$$(x_1-\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}},x_1+\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}) \times (y_1-\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}},y_1+\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}) \subset B_{\epsilon}(p)$$

and also that

$$B_{\epsilon}((x,y))\subset (a,b) \times (c,d)$$ for your choice of $\epsilon$.

This might be clear (and inspired from) a picture, but the computations here aren't that hard.

Add that and I'd give full marks.